# Найти сумму наименьшего и наибольшего числа из 3

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Дано числа a, b и c. Найти сумму наибольшего и наименьшего из этих чисел. Алгоритм должен быть оптимальным и иметь наименьшее возможное количество сравнений.
Я решил это так:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main()
{
    double a, b, c;
    cout << " Enter a = ";
    cin >> a;
    cout << " Enter b = ";
    cin >> b;
    cout << " Enter c = ";
    cin >> c;

    double Suma;

    if (a < b && a < c)
        if (b > a&&b > c)
            Suma = a + b;
        else
            if (c > a&&c > b)
                Suma = a + c;

    if (b < a&&b < c)
        if (a > b&&a > c)
            Suma = b + a;
        else
            if (c > a&&c > b)
                Suma = b + c;

    if (c < a&&c < b)
        if (a > b&&a > c)
            Suma = c + a;
        else
            if (b > a&&b > c)
                Suma = c + b;

    cout << " Suma : " << Suma << endl;
}
```

Напишите, пожалуйста, можно ли решить лучше

Comment: "сделайте за меня"  ?

Comment: если есть три числа, то минимальное кол-во сравнений - 3. Меньше никак.

Comment: можно за 2 с половиной "в среднем"

Comment: Не нужно вообще ни одного сравнения. `MAXi(a,b) = (a+b+ABS(a-b))/2` `MAXi(a,b,c)=MAXi(a,MAXi(b,c))`. Аналогично для минимального. И сложить.

Comment: мне нужно решить с условиями

Comment: @KoVadim, но тут  нужно  знать только, какая из них не минимальная и не максимальная, так что  есть возможность  получить результат двумя сравнениями

Comment: если я все правильно посчитал, то да, есть возможность в некоторых случаях обойтись двумя сравнениями. Но в общем случае все равно нужно три.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А вот и  с двумя сравнениями получается, если не нужно узнать какая из них минимальная, а какая максимальная. Главное найти средный из них:

```
int x,y, z;
cin >> x >> y >> z;
int d1 = x - y, d2 = x - z, d3 = y - x, d4 = y - z;
if (d1*d2 < 0) cout << y + z;
else if (d3*d4 < 0) cout << x + z;
else
    cout << y + x;
```

Comment: @goldstar_labs, я забыл про эту задачу, но вы напомнили, теперь оцените

Comment: Да, имеет место быть, спасибо за решение)

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum = max(x, max(y, z)) + min(x, min(y, z));
```

Comment: всеравно 3 сравнения

Comment: @ARHovsepyan 4 же

Comment: @goldstar_labs, да, даже 4